# How change the variables in braces

Tags: windows-10, conemu

My screen look like this (variables in braces)

[image: braces]

but I want, like this (with normal path , without braces)

[image: no-braces]

How do this ?

Comment: Do you want to remove them or change them? Please [edit] your question so that the body and title match.

Comment: I want to change them

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use cmder's config without clink or in bare ConEmu.

Solution: Don't do that. Configure original ConEmu for your taste without trying to adapt third-party configs. First of all, [run](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsStartup.html) original ConEmu's [task {cmd}](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTasks.html) instead of cmder's one.

Comment: I fixed , by download latest clink version (v0.4.7) from here https://github.com/mridgers/clink/releases. Thank you...